# Python: How to create loop for compare the values in row by row pandas

Tags: python, pandas, loops, csv

I am still a new python user and trying to make a longest common subsequence by using python. but I would like to know how to create a loop for comparing the value in row by row first. Here is a sample of the data.

```
row col1  col2  col3  col4   col5  col6 
0   'A'   '11'  'B'   '122'   ''    '' 
1   'A'   '11'  'B'   '122'  '121'  '' 
2   'A'   '12'  'B'   '123'  '124'  '' 
3   'A'   '13'  'B'   '123'  '124'  '456'
```

here is the sample code of LCS that I am going to adapt.

```
import pandas as pd

df_hier = pd.read_csv("sample.csv")

row1 = df_hier.iloc[1:2, 2:20]
row2 = df_hier.iloc[3:4, 2:20]

    def lcs(s1, s2):
        matrix = [["" for x in range(len(s2))] for x in range(len(s1))]
        for i in range(len(s1)):
            for j in range(len(s2)):
                if s1[i] == s2[j]:
                    if i == 0 or j == 0:
                        matrix[i][j] = s1[i]
                    else:
                        matrix[i][j] = matrix[i-1][j-1] + s1[i]
                else:
                    matrix[i][j] = max(matrix[i-1][j], matrix[i][j-1], key=len)

        cs = matrix[-1][-1]

        return len(cs), cs

    print(lcs(row1, row2))
```

Assumed that

```
the row1 will use 
'A'   '11'  'B'   '122'  '121'  '' 
and row2
'A'   '12'  'B'   '123'  '124'  ''
```

the expecting result will be

(7, 'A1B1212')

Comment: Finding it quite hard to figure out what the end goal of this code is, can you give an expected output?

Comment: It's like, assumed that

the row1 will use 
'A'   '11'  'B'   '122'  '121'  '' 
and row2
'A'   '12'  'B'   '123'  '124'  ''
the expecting result will be

(7, 'A1B1212')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that difficult. You just need to form pairs of values with zip and apply the `lcs` function you already have. Try this functions:

```
def lcs_rows(r1, r2):
    pairs = zip(r1.values.flatten(), r2.values.flatten())
    lcss = [lcs(*x) if len(x[0]) and len(x[1]) else (0, '') for x in pairs]
    nums = [x[0] for x in lcss]
    strs = [x[1] for x in lcss]
    return (sum(nums), ''.join(strs))
```

Comment: got it, Thank you so much

Comment: i am sorry to keep asking but i wonder that if the column is not contain '' but it equals to Nan like this
the row1 will use 

'A'   '11'  'B'   '122'  '121'  NaN 
and row2
'A'   '12'  'B'   '123'  '124'  NaN

 lcss = [lcs(*x) if len(x[0]) and len(x[1]) else (0, NaN) for x in pairs but it shows error ;__; how can i fix this situation? T T i have tried to fix but but i can't TT